# Multisite network admin login redirect

Tags: multisite, redirect, network-admin

I have a multisite with two different domain names.

I had an issue where I could log in to `www.domain1.com/wp-admin` and the Network Admin just fine, but if I try to log in to `www.domain2.com/wp-admin`, I'm getting the following error after submitting login details:

> *ERROR: cookies are blocked or not supported by your browser. You must enable cookies to use WordPress.*

I got around this by adding the following code to the wp-config.php:

```
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
```

However, when this code is in place I can access `www.domain1.com/wp-admin` and `www.domain2.com/wp-admin` but if I try to log in to Network Admin the login page just refreshes instead of going to the Dashboard.

This is what the multi site code in my wp-config.php looks like:

```
/* Multi site code */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', 'false');
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'domain1.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] );
/* That's all, stop editing! Happy publishing. */
```

Comment: Just to check: when you say "log in to Network Admin" you mean login to the admin pages at all, you don't mean that you can get into admin but the 'network' menu doesn't work? You'll need to debug what cookies are being set and why the code doesn't think they're valid on refresh. It may be easiest to just use domain1.com though - do you definitely need both?

Comment: @Rup - I need both domains as they are essentially two different websites. I can currently switch between the two back-ends using the menu in WordPress admin, but if I switch to 'Network admin' to install a plugin for example, it will ask for my login details and I cannot get past that page as it just refreshes without an error message.